# How can I have Barcode Image on Landscape Jasper print in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

Could anyone help me in this, I am not able to scan the barcode Image that i am setting on a Report from iReport when i am putting that report in Landscape, But it does get scanned when The report is in Portrait .

Comment: What barcode type are you having this problem with?